# Jest test failed "TypeError: Path must be a string. Recieved undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

got this fail on ANY es6/require() exporting to jest test file:

`const path = require('path');`

```
Fail src\util\datetime.test.js
TypeError: Path must be a string. Rrecieved undefined
at assertPath(path.js:8:11)
at Object.win32.relative(path.js:256:3)
```

Node 4.5.0, npm 2.15.9

Jest 19.0.0, babel-jest: 21.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer in `babel-jest` and `babel-preset-jest` version. When i lower version of this packages, all works well